# CRM 2013: Workflow confusion

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using CRM2013 on-premise, and I have a simple background workflow setup, to email the assignee, when a record is assigned to another person. This workflow works as is expected, however if I share the same record and grant "Assign" permissions (R/W), they workflow does not send the e-mail.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is "Assign" via Share different than the owernship assign? If so, is it possible to modify my workflow to trigger on "assigned" records when they have been shared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you share a record with another user and select Assign, you are not assigning the record to the other user. The ownership of the shared record will not change. Instead you are giving the other user the permission to be able to assign the shared record to another user.

Your workflow should still fire if the user you shared the record with assigns the record to someone else.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation and clarification.